Meaning of phase disappearance (multiphase flows)
I am trying to understand the meaning of "phase disappearance" in the context of multiphase flows. For simplicity, I'll frame the question with respect to two phase two component flow.
Consider a medium $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ where there are two flowing phases, say water and gas. Let us assume that each phase has two components. I am studying a mathematical model which allows for components to be exchanged across the phases. For instance, gas may dissolve into water and H2O may dissolve into gas.
There is a constituent law which states that the phase saturations must sum to one ($S_w+S_g = 1$). I understand that $S_w,S_g$ are functions of space $(x,y,z)\in \Omega$ and time $t$.
I've read the following definition for "disappearance of the gas phase": Over time, the state of the system may change, so that $S_g=0$.
My confusion lies in the fact that $S_w,S_g$ are functions of $(x,y,z)$ and time $t$. Does disappearance of the gas phase mean: If at some time $t$ we have

any point in $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in \Omega$ where $S_g(x_0,y_0,z_0,t)=0$?
$S_g(x,y,z,t)=0$ for all $(x,y,z)\in \Omega$ ($S_g$ is identically the zero function on the entire domain $\Omega$)?

